# jQuery children() method is "selecting" grandchild when inline CSS is used

Tags: jquery, css, children

I was studying usage of jQuery children() method using below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_children2

I tried replicating the same output using inline CSS, but the text color of span(grandchild) is coming red. Please see the below code and advise. I understand this is not the right way to write a code and span is inheriting red color from parent li, just need to learn the logic behind it as why the results of style sheet and inline CSS is different?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".child").children().css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  body (great-grandparent)
  <div style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black">
    div (grandparent)

    <ul style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black" class="child">ul (direct parent)

      <li style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black">
        li (child)

        <span style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black; display:block">span (grandchild)</span> </li>

      <li style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black">
        li (child)

        <span style="padding:10px; margin:10px; border:1px solid black; display:block">span (grandchild)</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The text of span(grandchild) should have been in black color.

Comment: Where do you set the span color black? The red color is inherited from li tag (according to your jQuery code). Ps after <ul> you can't write the text outside an <li>

Comment: in the example there is a css rule which generally sets the text color to gray

Comment: Hey @Sfili_81, thanks for your message. I chose to use default black color so didnt specify color. Also,  writing a text outside <li> is intentional. This is replicated from w3schools link . Pls see this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_traversing_children2

Comment: your code works as expected, you don't set no color and so the child inherit from it's parent. Try to use this site instead of w3school, it is more updated [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance)

Comment: `li>span` inherits colour from `li` - if you don't specify colour of `span` then it will be the colour of `li`.   From the comments, it appears this was a misunderstanding, so there's no longer a question - please confirm.